# What does further education mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, adverbs

> A college of further education

I am wondering what is this? what is further education?? would you please explain it in more detail or introduce me to a site or source in such a way that I could study that?

Comment: I see that *further education* might be a British English usage, so someone else may be able to answer the question, since I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: I am wondering where you found this phrase. (Obviously, you've seen or heard it _somewhere_; why not add that information to your question?)

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a source? where did you find this phrase?

Comment: As a Brit, I understand *"further education"* (or *"higher education"*) to mean any "academic" education (not including, for example, apprenticeships) beyond the legal minimum. You used to be able to leave school at 16, but I think it's being extended to 18 within the next couple of years. Some people will ***currently*** classify GCE "A" levels obtained while staying on a school to age 18 as "further education", but presumably that will change soon (it's pointless calling something "further" if *everybody* has to have it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting point. I'd always considered "further education", "higher education" and "tertiary education" to refer to the same thing: university-level education.

Comment: @starsplusplus: My school had about 1200 pupils when I was a pupil back in the 60s, and only 5 in my year-group stayed beyond the legal minimum (two of them just for a year, to retake O-levels). Carsmack is right to point out that some people would call A-levels "further education", reserving "higher education" for degrees. But the precise meanings obviously vary between linguistic communities and over time, since the only reason either term exists is to identify a level of education that goes beyond "standard, legal minimum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has an article on [further education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Further_education).

**Further education** (often abbreviated FE) in the United Kingdom and Ireland, similar to **continuing education** in the United States, is a term used to refer to education (in addition to that received at secondary school), that is distinct from the higher education offered in universities. It may be at any level above compulsory secondary education, from basic skills training to higher vocational qualifications such as PGCE, NVQ, City and Guilds, BTEC, HNC, HND or Foundation Degree.

A distinction is usually made between FE and higher education HE, an education at a higher level than secondary school, usually provided in distinct institutions such as universities. FE in the United Kingdom is usually a means to attain an intermediate or follow up qualification necessary to attend university, or begin a specific career path, e.g. Quantity Surveyor, Town Planner or Veterinary Surgeon, for anyone over 16, primarily available at Colleges of Further Education, work-based learning, or adult and community learning institutions.